# How to check match with more keywords with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate

Is it a way to create a `NSPredicate` which checks not only one keyword match, but more keywords?

I know `"CONTAINS[cd] %@", var` operation which allow to filter like this:

string: "`aaa bbb ccc ddd`", keyword: "`aaa`" -> this will match,

but how to filter this:

string: "`aaa bbb ccc ddd`", keywords: "`aaa ccc`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need `|` or operator.

Something like `aaa|ccc`